# Is the Thing a man covered in rocks or a man made of rocks?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, the-thing

A member of the Fantastic Four, pilot Ben Grimm is transformed into the super-strong, ultra-durable rock man known as the Thing after cosmic radiation mutates him and the rest of his team. The Thing has one of the most iconic looks in comics, but I am not familiar enough with his physiology to know if he is just a regular human covered in rocks or if he is completely made of rocks. If a doctor was somehow able to draw blood with a syringe, would it be blood or some weird dirt-mud fluid?

Comment: Or are we all made of rocks and he's made of pudding?

Comment: Marvel Handbook Vol. 1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9eVl.png

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166400/23243 is also relevant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initially, it was not actual rock, but a "rock-like hide". Over the years (and changes in his powers), it's become more rocky in appearance, and is more often referred to as being actual stone. However, there is still flesh beneath the surface. In *Fantastic Four: Road Trip*, a poison by the Mad Thinker removes his powers, and the tough skin falls off, revealing soft skin below. He has also [had his armor removed through violence in the past](https://screenrant.com/hulk-marvel-fantastic-four-thing-stone/), revealing flesh below.

[image: Ben Grimm with revealed flesh after Wolverine claws him]

[image: Ben with exposed pulpy insides after a punch from The Hulk and headbutting him]